# "TypeError: track.attach is not a function" in React-Twilio Video Application

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

My Twilio React-Video Application works fine   for both Local and Remote Participants over Web(and Mobile Browser)

When I try to connect to the same "Room"  and all the necessary details from Twilio Android-SDK-Flutter plugin,I get this Error

```
track.attach() is not a function
```

```js
componentDidMount() {
        const { track } = this.props;
        track.attach(this.media.current);
    }
// Error : track.attach() is not a function
```

I am able to `console.log( )` the Remote Participant who joins the room but I am unable to view the Remote Participant.

> In Mobile Application,it is working fine and "both" the participants are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The normal cause for something like this is that you are using `participant.tracks` to get the tracks. However, [`participant.tracks` is actually a Map of `<Track.SID, TrackPublication>`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.9.0/docs/Participant.html) and a [`TrackPublication` does not have an `attach` method](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.9.0/docs/RemoteTrackPublication.html).

Instead, you should check if the [`TrackPublication#isSubscribed`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.9.0/docs/RemoteTrackPublication.html). If it is, you can then use `trackPublication.track.attach`. If the track is not yet subscribed you should listen for the [`"subscribed"` event](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.9.0/docs/RemoteTrackPublication.html#event:subscribed__anchor) which tells you that the track is now available.

You likely don't want to render the component that is trying to attach the track until the track is subscribed.

Let me know if that helps at all.